# Why terminal display in Win10Terminal is treated differently? [telnet to a remote Linux] vs [run WSL2 natively]

Tags: terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux, terminal-emulator

I'm very baffled with a such a question. I believe it relates to those esoteric "Terminal" working details, so I hope I can get concrete technical answer here.

I have two lab machines:

- An Ubuntu 22.04 with IP=10.22.4.47, who has telnet server enabled.
- A Windows 10 22H2 PC, who has WSL2 Ubuntu 22.04 installed.

I find that,

- If, from a [Win10Terminal](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9N0DX20HK701)(the Terminal program provided by Windows App Store), I telnet to the Ubuntu machine and run `iftop`, the display is garbled.
- If I run `wsl.exe` to launch a WSL instance, then `iftop` there displays well, box-drawing characters displayed very well.

I'd like to know:

- (1) why they exhibit such difference, and
- (2) how can I telnet.exe to a remote Linux and get good display results.

[Figure 1] Prepare to connect or launch Linux environments.

[image]

[Figure 2] Ready to launch `sudo iftop`.

Note that, I have explicitly assigned env-var `TERM=xterm` to `iftop`, but, that does not seem to be the panacea.

[image]

[Figure 3] telnet case and wsl case, give different terminal text "output", the telnet one is garbled.

[image]

Comment: Don't use telnet, use ssh. Don't use Win terminal, use something like putty instead.

Comment: Benefit of telnet is, I can use Wireshark to capture pristine character sequences to ease further investigation. I've actually tried PuTTY 0.79  before Win10Terminal, and PuTTY running with default settings exhibits its own behavior, different to the garbled display and the great display(third case, box drawing characters displayed as `m`, `q`, `v` etc). So, to make my first question a bit focused, I refer to only telnet case and WSL case. Unix terminal control protocol is quite complicated, and I'm stilled stumbled.